# How to check if Azure Blob file Exists or Not

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to check a particular file exist in Azure Blob Storage. Is it possible to check by specifying it's file name? Each time i got File Not Found Error.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642919/checking-if-a-blob-exists-in-azure-storage Check it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a blob exists in Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642919/checking-if-a-blob-exists-in-azure-storage)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This extension method should help you:

```
public static class BlobExtensions
{
    public static bool Exists(this CloudBlob blob)
    {
        try
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            return true;
        }
        catch (StorageClientException e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorCode == StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var blob = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount
        .CreateCloudBlobClient().GetBlobReference(args[0]);
    // or CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<your connection string>")

    if (blob.Exists())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The blob exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The blob doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there is a different way to check for the existence of the blob.

Comment: Note: this doesn't work anymore with the new SDK. The other answers are the solution.

Answer (score 40):

```
var blob = client.GetContainerReference(containerName).GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);

if (blob.Exists())
 //do your stuff
```

Comment: Try adding some context for your code to help the person asking the question.

Answer (score 14):

With the updated SDK, once you have the CloudBlobReference you can call Exists() on your reference.

**UPDATE**

The relevant documentation has been moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.exists?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_Exists_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_

**My implementation using WindowsAzure.Storage v2.0.6.1**

```
    private CloudBlockBlob GetBlobReference(string filePath, bool createContainerIfMissing = true)
    {
        CloudBlobClient client = _account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("my-container");

        if ( createContainerIfMissing && container.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            //Public blobs allow for public access to the image via the URI
            //But first, make sure the blob exists
            container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
        }

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);

        return blob;
    }

    public bool Exists(String filepath)
    {
        var blob = GetBlobReference(filepath, false);
        return blob.Exists();
    }
```

Comment: but it always return false. Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Verify the visibility of your bucket and the file itself. If it's publicly visible, try accessing it via a browser. Could be your URI is incorrect.

Comment: I am getting the name with .ListBlobs() on the same BlobService instance, so it should not be visibility/permission problem.

Comment: @d.popov - I'm have the same problem here.  Verified file does exist, but exists() is always returning false.  Haven't solved the problem yet...

Comment: @BabakNaffas: I'll just say that the page where your link reference to, is not longer available.

Comment: Was this ever solved? Exists always returns "false" for me as well.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I have updated the answer with my implementation using the Exists method. This has been working for me in production for a couple years.

Comment: @BabakNaffas, thanks for the update.  My code is basically the same, but I added the line here per your recommendation to call the .SetPermissions() method as you did above, but that does not seem to be changing the behavior.  I'm still getting a return value of "false" from the .Exists() method.  Perhaps there's something else I'm missing?

Comment: @AdamLevitt make sure it's not a casing issue.

Comment: @BabakNaffas - thanks for your continued replies.  It's not a casing issue.  Just triple checked that.  I'm definitely still getting a false for exists.  It's very strange, and surprisingly that it's this difficult to get this to work.

Comment: NOTE: As of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.1.4.0 (.Net Framework v4.6.2) The Exists() method doesn't exist in favour of ExistsAsync() Which is the version that will install for .NetCore projects

Answer (score 6):

Using the new package `Azure.Storage.Blobs`

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("YourStorageConnectionString");
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("YourContainerName");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("YourFileName");
```

then check if exists

```
if (blobClient.Exists()){
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ExistsAsync` method of CloudBlockBlob.

```
bool blobExists = await cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("<name of blob>").ExistsAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob version 4.3.0.0**, the following code should work (there are a lot of breaking changes with older versions of this assembly):

Using container/blob name, and the given API (seems now Microsoft have actualy implemented this):

```
return _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName).GetBlockBlobReference(blobName).Exists();
```

Using blob URI (workaround):

```
  try 
  {
      CloudBlockBlob cb = (CloudBlockBlob) _blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri(url));
      cb.FetchAttributes();
  }
  catch (StorageException se)
  {
      if (se.Message.Contains("404") || se.Message.Contains("Not Found"))
      {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
```

(Fetch attributes will fail if the blob is not existing. Dirty, I know :)

Comment: @Steve, does this help? what version of the Storage client are you using?

Comment: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException` has `RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode`. For non-existent blobs it will be HTTP/404.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of SDK, you need to use the [`ExistsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_ExistsAsync) Method,

```
public async Task<bool> FileExists(string fileName)
{
    return  await directory.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).ExistsAsync();
}
```

Here is the [code sample](https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/8067ec04b41344bbc1ee5c06e0282564).

Answer (score 2):

This complete example is here to help.

```
public class TestBlobStorage
{

    public bool BlobExists(string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(@"<connection string here>");

        var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        
        var blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        return blob.Exists();

    }

}
```

then you can test in main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TestBlobStorage t = new TestBlobStorage();

        Console.WriteLine("blob exists: {0}", t.BlobExists("image-test", "AE665.jpg")); 

        Console.WriteLine("--done--");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Important** I found the file names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
## dbutils.widgets.get to call the key-value from data bricks job

storage_account_name= dbutils.widgets.get("storage_account_name")
container_name= dbutils.widgets.get("container_name")
transcripts_path_intent= dbutils.widgets.get("transcripts_path_intent")
# Read azure blob access key from dbutils 
storage_account_access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "inteliserve-blob-storage-secret-scope", key = "storage-account-key")

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=storage_account_name, account_key=storage_account_access_key)

def blob_exists():
        container_name2 = container_name
        blob_name = transcripts_path_intent
        exists=(block_blob_service.exists(container_name2, blob_name))
        return exists
blobstat = blob_exists()
print(blobstat)
```