# Checking if container and blob exist in Azure Blob Storage using built in Exists method

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I found this extension method to check Blob storage exists

[Testing Existence of a Windows Azure Blob](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob)

[Checking if a blob exists in Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642919/296861)

However, I found similar build in utility methods inside `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`.

- `CloudBlobContainer.Exists`
- `CloudBlockBlob.Exists`

As far as I tested, they function similar to the extension method.

### Question:

Are they new utility methods? Should I use build in `Exists` method or use custom extension method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Steve wrote in his blog post is truly an extension method and thus not part of the core library however the methods you mentioned are part of core storage client library. My recommendation would be to use the methods which are part of core library as they would be kept up-to-date if anything changes in the library.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could find that in documentation. It might be very new.