# Azure BlobClient downloadToFile() throws java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

As the title says, I am getting the java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException when trying to use the downloadToFile method. I read some doc and it says that the way this method works is that if the file exists, it will throw a FileAlradyExistsException which happened to me when I manually created the file. But I find it weird that when the file doesn't exist, it throws the opposite...

```
        String localPath = "/Download/"; // this is the path within my server
        BlobClient blobClient;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            blobClient = container.getBlobClient(files[i]);


            blobClient.downloadToFile(localPath + files[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642919/checking-if-a-blob-exists-in-azure-storage is this helpful

Comment: Unfortunately not, this checks if the blob exists. In my case, I want to create the file in my specified folder.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You want to download file or to upload it. In blob storage there is no folders at all. If you want to upload file why do you use download method

Comment: I am trying to download...

Comment: @zolty13 My precise expectation (even though it was already precise) : I want to take a blob on azure and make it a file in my server.

Comment: I tried this and many other docs, but nothing works... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=bash#download-blobs

Comment: The file you want download does not exists on azure blob storage so you receive `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`. `FileAlradyExistsException` is thrown when file with such a name already exists at your local file system, in your case it is your server

Comment: then how do I check if the file exists?

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, the blobClient.exists() returns true.

Comment: `Sep. 24, 2021 4:12:40 P.M. com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger performLogging
SEVERE: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Download/User_Manual/manual.pdf`

Comment: Does path for this new downloaded file exists? /Download/User_Manual

Comment: no, otherwise it would throw the `FileAlradyExistsException`

Comment: Please provide more code. Also with you tryings with File Exists method.

Comment: Forget it, I fixed it...

Comment: So please provide answer below. Good night

Comment: It still doesn't work ideally, I will provide it when I'm done!

Comment: You need to ensure that “User_Manual” folder exists inside your “Download” folder. SDK will not create this folder for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gaurav Mantri mentioned, the folder itself had to be present. So I had to build all the folders and now the files load perfectly.